# Properties order of the state changes on submit handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have this code, where on ChangeText in react native, i am inserting multiple field values in the state, item. For some reason, the output in the console log shows alphabetical order. Since the logic is, that on ChangText, the function EnterValue inserts the value in item state. it finds the property name and then matches that to the text value, I think something gets wrong along the way. Please see  below the code

```js
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      step: 1,
      TotalItem: [],
      item: {
        Brand: null,
        Quantity: null,
        Instructions: null,
      },
    };
  }

  // remember this logig since take names, it adds property values in alphabetical order, and thus change the order
  EnterValue = (name) => {
    return (text) => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        item: { ...prevState.item, [name]: text },
      }));
    };
  };

  submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e);

    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      step: step + 1,
    });

    this.setState(
      {
        TotalItem: [...this.state.TotalItem, this.state.item],
      },
      () => {
        console.log("updated state", this.state.TotalItem);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 20 }}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="enter name"
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Brand")}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "skyblue", margin: 20 }}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Quantity"
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Quantity")}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "skyblue", margin: 20 }}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder="Instructions"
          onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Instructions")}
          style={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: "skyblue", margin: 20 }}
        />

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button
              style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}
              title="add"
              onPress={this.add}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button
              style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }}
              title="submit"
              onPress={this.submit}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: can you please add an example of actual vs expected outputs?

Comment: Expected should be my state item. and its properties should appear in order, like shown in the state. However, in console.log after submit, the properties appear in alphabetical order, like Brand, Instructions, Quantity

Comment: That's because you execute the function on the JSX

Comment: Hey, found your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```js
onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Quantity")}
onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Brand")} 
onChangeText={this.EnterValue("Instructions ")}
```

To

```js
onChangeText={() => this.EnterValue("Quantity")}
onChangeText={() => this.EnterValue("Brand")} 
onChangeText={() => this.EnterValue("Instructions ")}
```

Comment: sorry for late response. but that does not populate state. i just checked. thanks